# What are the default values of kernel size and padding in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

For an instance, take this piece of code :

```
conv = conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64)
```

What can I expect the padding and kernel size to be, by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> class torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True)

So to answer your question, by default `padding=0`, there is no default value for `kernel_size`. If you leave it empty, you will get an error

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful